# Thin throws error: undefined method "call"

Tags: ruby, debian, rack, thin, gentoo

I'm having trouble getting thin to run my webapp. It starts up just fine, but whenever I make a request thin craps out and I get the following popping up in the log:

```
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
!! Unexpected error while processing request: undefined method `call'
   for #<Rack::Request:0x7f104facb640>
```

This configuration worked just fine on my Debian server; I'm running Gentoo now.

This is my rackup file:

```
require 'toto'
# Rack config
use Rack::Static, :urls => ['/css', '/js', '/images', '/favicon.ico', '/pubkey.asc'], :root => 'public'
use Rack::Request
use Rack::CommonLogger
if ENV['RACK_ENV'] == 'development'
  use Rack::ShowExceptions
end
#
# Create and configure a toto instance
#
toto = Toto::Server.new do
#
 # Add your settings here
 # set [:setting], [value]
 #
 set :author,    "jibcage"                               # blog author
 set :title,     "Going to Grass"                   # site title
 set :root,      "index"                                   # page to load on /
 # set :date,      lambda {|now| now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") }  # date format for articles
 set :markdown,  :smart
```

Comment: Can we see your web app code which handles requests?

Comment: I added my rackup file up top.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the line

```
use Rack::Request
```

Comment: `Rack::Request` isn't a `Rack` middleware.